# Angular rxjs Subject, Component didn't received the data sent by Subject

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a notification service in Angular. To do this I have a NotificationService that contains a frequently updated list of notifications. This Service exposes a Subject that allows me to send my notification list to the Component.

In a Component, I get this list with a Subscription.
But when I create new notifications, these are not retrieved by the Component.

NotificationService :

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationService{
    notifications$: Observable<Notification[]>;    

    private _notificationsSubject: ReplaySubject<Notification[]>;
    private _notifications = new Array<Notification>();

    constructor() {
        this._notificationsSubject = new ReplaySubject<Notification[]>();    
        this.notifications$ = this._notificationsSubject.asObservable();
    }

    createNotification() { 
        const notification = new Notification();
        this._notifications = [...this._notifications, notification];
        this._notificationsSubject.next(this._notifications);
    }

    ...
}
```

NotificationPanelComponent :

```
export class NotificationPanelComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  
      notifications!: Notification[];    
      notificationSub!: Subscription;
  
      constructor(
          private _notificationService: NotificationService
      ) { 
        this.notificationSub = this._notificationService.notifications$
            .subscribe((notifications) => {
                this.notifications = notifications;
        });
      }
      ...
}
```

When I create a Notification in the Service constructor, it is well received by the Component.
When I create a Notification outside the Service Builder, it is never received by the Component (but it is created).

I don't understand what's wrong with my code.

Comment: What do you mean "it is never received"? What do you get if you put `{{ (_notificationService.notifications$ | async)?.length }}` in your component template code? (declare the field public in the constructor for the view to catch it)

Comment: in your createNotification method, the argument is getting overridden by const notification =  new Notification(). you pass a notification, but then reassign it as a new notification, so it is then an empty notification and the argument is unused. tslint should give you the 'duplicate identifier' error. It could be part of your issue.

Comment: When I declare field public ` public _notificationService: NotificationService` and put `{{ (_notificationService.notifications$ | async)?.length }}` it doesn't change anything, it acts as if _notificationService.notifications$ is null.

Comment: @BenBradshaw Indeed it is overwritten in this context but it is not the problem. A notification is successfully created but doesn't get to the component

Comment: show your providers and their configuration

Comment: What is the changeDetection strategy for NotificationPanelComponent? if it's onPush change it to default.